# Accordian effect in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to expand a cell in my table view when I select it. Initially it should look like this:

[image]

And on expanding, it should give more detail like this:

[image]

This is how I'm creating the cell initially:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, 
        cell.textLabel.frame.size.height);
 }
 id key = [[articles allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 cell.textLabel.text =@"TitleTitleTitle";        
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"DeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatai";
 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published a sample code at [github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/blob/master/ExtendingCells/Classes/FirstViewController.m)

Your `tabelView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` could look like this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, 
                                          cell.textLabel.frame.size.height);
    }
    id key = [[articles allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text =@"TitleTitleTitle";        
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"DeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatailDeatai";


    //SEE MY NOTE BELOW
    if([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath]){
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=0;

        CGSize constraintSize;
        constraintSize.width = cell.textLabel.frame.size.width;
        constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
        cell.textLabel.frame = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize];

        constraintSize.width = cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width;
        constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
        cell.detailTextLabel.frame = [cell.detailTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.detailTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=1;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=1;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**BUT**
You will also need the height of the cell by dynamic in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, so you should refactor the sizing parts into a helper methods, that writes the sizes of the 2 labels and the height of the cell to ivars, call the method from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, use the cell height there and the labels sizes in `tabelView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: hi, its working and getting the effect what i want. thanks for it.but i am not able to add detail text to cell when it expands.how should i show it on expansion?

Comment: Are u using a custom cell or a certain per-defined style?

Comment: please post the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your original question.

Comment: see my edit (PS: please leave a comment after altering your question/answer, as otherwise people won't be notified. also post proper formatted code with proper intention)

Comment: tabelView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is not get called when row expands.I get called when row get contract.so unable to show as per requirement.:(

Comment: see my `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implementation. It updates the tableview -> `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called.

Comment: thanks for help. i called [table reloadData] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and its work for me.thanku