# Best Way To Implement Accordian in UITableView

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I want to implement accordian in only one of my UITableView rows (second row maybe)  and I want to implement this without using any custom class or custom cell class. Clicking on the accordian row 'n' rows should be added under that row and I also want to track that rows didSelectRow() delegate method for that row and also for other rows independently. What is the best way to do it any help is appreciated.

[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325262/how-to-give-accordian-effect-to-table-row-iphone)

Comment: What would you even post this if you already knew it was a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this once with a Plain UITableView, without any custom cells, with the help of the method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. I used this method to design the headers of each section as a button to collapse/expand its rows.

You should maintain an array of booleans that indicates whether a specific section is expanded, i.e. its rows are visible. This array should start with all values false. Then when a section header is clicked, you should change its value in the array to true.

The method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` will return 0 if that section is collapsed or the number of rows in that section if it's expanded.

Finally you should use the `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` method to animate the expanding/collapsing.